# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Eclipselink_JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm new to JPA and I'm pretty lost in this.

I created an enterprise project in netbeans to do some tests. Created this persistence unit with the wizard. I added it a JNDI connection that works proper and it's already tested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistencia" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/nuevaConexion</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Later, I created a sample entity with some test variables to see how this works:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nombre;
    private int numero;
    /**
     * @return the serialVersionUID
     */
    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    /**
     * @param aSerialVersionUID the serialVersionUID to set
     */
    public static void setSerialVersionUID(long aSerialVersionUID) {
        serialVersionUID = aSerialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

   // setters & getters
```

Then, tried to make the service CreateEntity1 to give it a try, and try to create a new element on the DB by calling it:

```
public class CreateEntity1 {

   public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

      EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "Eclipselink_JPA" );      
      EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

      Entity1 ent = new Entity1( ); 
      ent.setId(1);
      ent.setNombre("Mi entidad");
      ent.setNumero(123);

      entitymanager.persist( ent );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );
      entitymanager.close( );
      emfactory.close( );
   }
}
```

... but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No
>   Persistence provider for EntityManager named Eclipselink_JPA  at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>     at service.CreateEntity1.main(CreateEntity1.java:22)
>   C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I changed the name of the persistence provider to the good one, but now I'm getting a serious bunch of errors.

EDIT 2: Changed everything to Hibernate type. Still getting a huge error:

> Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack:  Exception
>   [EclipseLink-30009] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
>   Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to load
>   persistence unit at url:
>   file:/C:/Users/hp/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PruebasJ2EE/PruebasJ2EE-ejb/build/classes/
>   Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence
>   Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
>   Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing
>   persistence.xml from URL:
>   file:/C:/Users/hp/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PruebasJ2EE/PruebasJ2EE-ejb/build/classes/
>   Internal Exception:  (1. El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento
>   que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.)   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionLoadingFromUrl(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:100)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:616)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.getPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:500)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchive(JPAInitializer.java:178)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:160)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>     at service.CreateEntity1.main(CreateEntity1.java:22) Caused by:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
>   Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing
>   persistence.xml from URL:
>   file:/C:/Users/hp/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PruebasJ2EE/PruebasJ2EE-ejb/build/classes/
>   Internal Exception:  (1. El destino de la instrucción de procesamiento
>   que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.)   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionProcessingPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:665)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:614)
>     ... 8 more Caused by:  (1. El destino de la instrucción de
>   procesamiento que coincide con "[xX][mM][lL]" no está permitido.)     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.xml.parser.XMLExceptionHandler.error(XMLExceptionHandler.java:28)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.xml.parser.XMLExceptionHandler.fatalError(XMLExceptionHandler.java:34)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:180)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:723)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1018)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:691)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:655)
>     ... 9 more
>   C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Try with `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistencia" );`, you have to specify the correct persistence unit name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my anwser at my anwser at [Simplest working example of Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826933/simplest-working-example-of-spring-data-jpa/27863674#27863674). To me it was simple enough. Hope it will be as simple to You.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `<provider>...` try to add it like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="persistencia" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   ...
```

Comment: It keeps failing; check the edit I'm going to do now

Comment: you do NOT have to specify provider if there is only 1 in the CLASSPATH